# jQuery tabs and form fields

Tags: jquery, forms

Another question from me to my jQuery UI tab learning and debugging days...

Expect I have 20 tabs with several input fields on it.

User switches between tabs and inputs some data in the input fields on the different tabs.

On the final tab there will be a check button.

1. What is the best way to check for the values in the different tabs and jump to the tab with a empty or false filled form field?
2. I got some working solutions to address the back button topic. Hitting the back button returns the user to the last tab where he was not the first. But how do I avoid that the user input in the tabs (the values are not yet stored in the database this will be done after clicking the check button) are lost, if the user hits the back button?

Comment: Is this homework? We will not do your homework for you....

Comment: @Neal based on vbd's other questions, I suspect not

Comment: @Neal, no homework. Trying to combine my own libraries with JS standard libs and find a solution with different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Use local storage to save the form data to their browser without bothering with the database.  Here is a [jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/localstorage) that can help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try posting some code so we'd have something more specific to work with. 
Second, since you're submitting a form, I will assume that all fields can be found inside a `form` tag. Note that I will also assume that you're only working with text fields.

Here's what you can try: http://jsfiddle.net/J4bas/1/

Using that, you can find the tab that holds the offending input field inside the if condition. Then maybe use the technique found here: [selecting & loading a jquery tab programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970838/selecting-loading-a-jquery-tab-programatically)

To load the tab, programatically.