# Select last tab by default on Page load, jQuery Ui Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to open the last tab in a jQuery Tabs on DOM ready but the solutions I have found online do not seem to be working. I am using vertical tabs as per the example in the jQuery UI Demo site.

JS -

```
$( "#personnelStats_tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#personnelStats_tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
```

CSS -

```
.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em; }
```

Comment: Left out a very key detail in my question. I am trying to open the last tab by default when the page loads

Comment: possible duplicate of [selecting & loading a jquery tab programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970838/selecting-loading-a-jquery-tab-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, everyone. Unfortunately, I was not specific enough in my question (wrote it in too much of a hurry) and the solution was not given here. However, a link to a similar post from 2009 that I somehow missed and the use of `.last()` helped me find a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Initiate jQuery Tabs
    var $tabs = $( "#personnelStats_tabs" ).tabs();
    //Get the index of the last tab
    var last = $(".ui-tabs-nav li").last().index();
    //Add hack for vertical tabs
    $tabs.addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#personnelStats_tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
    //Select the last tab
    $tabs.tabs("select", last);
});
```

Thanks folks! +1 to all of you

Answer (score 3):

Get the last element with [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
$(".ui-tabs-nav li").last()
```

Comment: Yeah, guess you updated it now. Sometimes I feel that the `:last` selector doesn't work well in IE browsers.

Comment: given you ups anyway, this guy seems to have abandoned the question, good day!

Comment: Thanks buddy, same to you! :P

Comment: Did not abandon, sorry! Yesterday and today have been hectic. Wrote the question in a hurry and left out a key detail - - trying to open the page with the last tab open by default. Is that what using :last would accomplish?

Comment: @NightMICU Yeah, please try and check out if it works. :) It is working from my side.

Comment: Will be a few hours until I am at a work station, I'll post right away when I get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog/tutorial on jQueryUI tabs that might help.

http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/08/jqueryjqueryui-help-tabs-get-currently.html

ALSO, try:

```
// for last tab
$(".ui-tabs-nav li:last")
// with your code as shown
$("#personnelStats_tabs .ui-tabs-nav li:last")

// for last panel
$(".ui-tabs-panel:last")
// with your code as shown
$("#personnelStats_tabs .ui-tabs-panel:last")
```

Ouch, just realized there are changes in the new jquery and i have to update my blog! Why they change class names!

For more info, see [jQuery :last Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

You could also use jQuery's [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) function instead of the :last selector if you wanted.